# shapefile batch clip and merge combined

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, ogr, clip, merge

I have two shapefiles, one is polyline, the other polygon. For each polygon I would like to clip the polyline vectors inside. Using arcpy I already found part of a possible solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19934/6458

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\Projects\GDBs\slowbutter.gdb\IPAS'
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor('HspAOI')
for row in rows:
    feat = row.Shape
    arcpy.Clip_analysis('HspWBD_HU12', feat, 'HspWBD_HU12_' + str(row.getValue('NAME')), '')
```

This however would create a new shapefile per polygon. I have 8000 polygons and would have to merge these using arcpy.Merge_management().

Is there maybe a way to not have to merge 8000 separate shapefiles? I work with arcpy and ogr so the latter might also be an option?

Comment: Do your 8000 polygons have any overlap between them?

Comment: No, they are equal-area triangle polygons which share edges but no overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your polygons do not overlap I think you should try Intersect from the Analysis toolbox.

Comment: That did the trick!