# How can i project a coordinate system for many rasters all at once?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system

help
many rasters i have and should be projected in UTM coordinate system.
what should i do?

Comment: What tools do you have QGIS, ArcMAP etc... ? as not all are free

Comment: i have arcmap 10.2 on my notebook

Comment: You can use arcpy to loop through all files in an array and change projection.  link: http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000007q000000

Comment: let me check this issue............

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS you can use [batch processing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm) to run the re-projection tool on a large dataset. If it doesn't work on rasters than you can use the model builder to achieve the same thing by using iterators as shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84992/64540).

QGIS also has a [batch processing interface](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html) but I haven't used it myself, so I'm not sure how effective that is.

Your best bet might be to just use GDAL.

Comment: batch project is not usable for rasters.... it is usable for features
what should i do?

Comment: I have used the model builder to do something similar using rasters, you can try using the model builder to do this. something like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84992/64540 should work

Comment: i dont know how model builder works. please guide me thanks.

Comment: your best bet in that case is to try and use GDAL as shown in the question iant has marked this a duplicate of.

Comment: let me check this issue............