# Clipping Single Raster with Multiple Polygons in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am quite new to using iterators, and ModelBuilder in general. I have a .tiff format raster (not a feature class) and I would like to clip it with 18 polygon shapefiles which are spatially present within the raster extent.

I looked at some other model formulas, such as [Batch Clip in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84989/batch-clip-in-modelbuilder-of-arcgis-for-desktop)

But, I just can't seem to get it working in ArcGIS 10.2.

Any ideas how I can set up a model which would automate this process and export 18 unique clipped rasters?

---

I have edited below and added the final correct model.

[image]

Comment: why not merge all the shapefiles into one and then clip? Do you want 18 distinct raster outputs?

Comment: Without knowing much about model builder, if you are indeed looking for an output of 18 clipped rasters then I believe you have your rasters and feature classes flipped around and you should, instead, being iterating through the feature classes (polygon shapefiles).  There may be more that you need to get your model functioning, but that's a start.

Comment: I agree with @rumski20, you need to iterate over your 18 FeatureClasses (shapefiles) clipping your single raster. Make sure you are using inline substitution in the final clipped raster otherwise you just end up overwriting each clip.

Comment: Thanks guys - the reason I dont merge them all into one clip is because I need to automate this process for a specific workflow- and I need 18 unique raster files as an output. I am not sure what inline substitution is, but I am going to mess around a bit more right now based on all your advice- I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Hey guys- I got everything working except- as you said Hornbydd, I need an inline substitution. How exactly would I modify this so I don't have the outputs overwrite themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing off of your current model something like this should work.

[image]

As @Hornbydd mentioned using [inline substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_inline_model_variable_substitution/002w0000005w000000/) in the clip output will allow you to create unique output names so your output isn't overwritten each time. Also make sure you use the Clip (Data Management) tool for the raster clip.